# How to run 100 csv File in script file from a folder (One file at once)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I have to run the below script code for multiple files from a folder, one at once, I have change CSV file name at every iteration, file names are like D8.csv, D16.csv etc.

```
java -Xmx10G -jar dist/wikifier-3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -annotateData data/Splited_WikiQA_dev/**D8.csv** data/output_Splited_WikiQA_dev/ false configs/STAND_ALONE_NO_INFERENCE.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop that processes all the files matching a wildcard.

```
for file in data/Splited_WikiQA_dev/*.csv
do
    java -Xmx10G -jar dist/wikifier-3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -annotateData "$file" data/output_Splited_WikiQA_dev/ false configs/STAND_ALONE_NO_INFERENCE.xml
done
```

Comment: Some of the files are not saving in the output folder, how to keep those file name list in a separate file?

Comment: Why aren't they saving?

Comment: They are giving some error; I wanted to keep those file list separately. I am new to the shell script, can we do if else like logic here. Please suggest

Comment: If the `java` command sets its exit status based on the error you can use `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` to test this and do something. If not, there's no way for the script to tell if there's an error.